# How is it possible to have an user action in the "view" directory that trigger an ubus method?

Tags: view, lua, gpio, openwrt

I am trying to implement some code for a GUI using openwrt and luci.
I would like to know how to implement a button or a formulary that trigger a lua command when the user submit it.

I make a lua script using ubus to control gpios and relays and now I am trying to make a GUI in which users will be allowed to control each GPIO and relays through ubus commands.

I know the commands to call ubus methods through the GUI.
I did a new page with several graphic items. Is it possible to implement a button/formulary which changes a variable and this variable will be used by a lua script?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would help to see some of your code.

Comment: @JackTaylor Thank you for your answer, I have tried to use buttons to trigger an action such as     [code]        <button onclick="on_all()">Click</button>

<%
    fonction on_all(){
        luci.util.ubus("r_ubus", "on", {"relay"="all"})
%> [/code]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's two *simple* methods that can achieve this:

1. POST/GET request to controller.
2. Using Lua functions in the HTM.

The first one should not be hard to understand conceptually and you can read about POST/GET requests in JavaScript (AJAX) here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

The second option is fine for something incredibly simple (or for testing purposes), but I would advise against using it over the first one just because there is less to type. All you need to do is simply surround your Lua code with `<% (code goes here) %>`.

However, there is another way which does not rely on Lua/JavaScript at all. You can make a config file (as it does seem you are saving something to it) and make an init script launch the service/change some parameters after any change to the configuration file using procd. Here's an example of how to do that: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/procd-init-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Use curl commands, you can trigger a curl command when button is pressed and there by you can achieve your functionality